# Change direction of javafx RotateTransition to direction of clockwise

Tags: javafx, rotation, javafx-8, transition, image-rotation

in my javafx application, i have an imageView for which I have created an Rotate trasition, everything works fine , but the rotation direction is in counterclockwise of watch, i want to make it in opposite direction .

this is My code :

```
RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(3000), myImageView);
rt.setByAngle(360);
rt.setCycleCount(1);
rt.setAutoReverse(false);
rt.play()
```

;

Comment: Did you try specifying `-360` angle? Could be as simple as that...

Comment: Thanks @sillyfly your intelligent solution works :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be undocumented, but setting a negative angle results in a counter-clockwise rotation:

```
rt.setByAngle(-360);
```