# JavaxFX set NodeOrientation for the RotateTransition

Tags: javafx

I want to define an orientation for an object using the RotationTransition, but it only turns in one orientation. How i can change orientation when i use RotationTransition ?

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.NodeOrientation;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TestRotation extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle (100, 40, 100, 100);
    rect.setArcHeight(50);
    rect.setArcWidth(50);
    rect.setFill(Color.VIOLET);
    // Node Orientation doesn't work
    rect.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    rect.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

    RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(3000), rect);
    rt.setByAngle(360);
    rt.setAutoReverse(false);
    rt.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    rt.setCycleCount(TranslateTransition.INDEFINITE);
    rt.play();

    root.getChildren().add(rect);

    stage.show();

  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);
  }
}
```

Thanks you

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking/trying to do. The node orientation refers to the direction in which child nodes are laid out - this is usually only an issue when using languages which are written from right to left (such as Arabic, Hebrew, Farsi etc.). It makes little sense to change the orientation in a transition...

Comment: I want the Rectangle turn LEFT TO RIGHT or turn RIGHT TO LEFT. But i can not control that.

Comment: Do you mean the direction of rotation (clockwise vs counterclockwise)? If so - try setting the "by angle" to negative 360. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094481/change-direction-of-javafx-rotatetransition-to-direction-of-clockwise

Comment: YEAH thanks you : ), rt.setByAngle(-360); it works.